# Trouble with animation on UIImageView

Tags: ios, animation, imageview

I have 7 images which i'm trying to make fade in/out of 1 ImageView. I have stored all the images in an array, and then have a loop to display each image and fade into the next, however, when i run the program only the last 2 images show up. Any ideas on why this is? and how to fix it? Code is below.

```
imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image 0.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image 1.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image 2.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image 3.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image 4.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image 5.jpg"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image 6.jpg"],
              nil];
            self.imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
              self.imageview.clipsToBounds = YES;

int count = [imageArray count];
for (int i = 0; i <count-1 ; i++)
{
    UIImage *currentImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
    UIImage *nextImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i +1];
    self.imageview.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex: i];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageview];
    CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    crossFade.duration = 5.0;
    crossFade.fromValue = (__bridge id)(currentImage.CGImage);
    crossFade.toValue = (__bridge id)(nextImage.CGImage);
    [self.imageview.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];
    self.imageview.image = nextImage;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to note:

1) You are doing everything synchronously on a loop that has no delay between each transition, there's no point in animating a if on the next loop it will be replaced by the next and so on, until the last 2. Also, you are adding your `imageView` as a subview every time, also unnecessary.

2) You are changing the .image property of the `imageView`, and then changing the contents of the layer. Might as well use an UIView and have the same effect.

My recommendation is to make a method to swap from one image to the next, and have a `NSTimer` call the function every x amount of seconds until you passed through them all.

Edit: For the future:

```
self.imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.imageview.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

are completely unnecessary :)

The `.backgroundColor` is drawn over by the `UIImage` you are displaying.

The `.clipsToBounds` is the default behavior of `UIImageView` (it shrinks/expands your image to it's size, but never draws outside)